# SQL join category from timeline into timestamp table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Consider the following structure:

```
create table timestamps(id int, stamp timestamp);
insert into timestamps values
(1,'2017-10-01 10:05:01'),
(2,'2017-10-01 11:05:01'),
(3,'2017-10-01 12:05:01'),
(4,'2017-10-01 13:05:01');

create table category_timeline(begin timestamp,end timestamp, category varchar(100));
insert into category_timeline values
('2017-10-01 10:01:03','2017-10-01 12:01:03','Cat1'),
('2017-10-01 12:01:03','2017-10-01 12:42:43','Cat3'),
('2017-10-01 12:42:43','2017-10-01 14:01:03','Cat2');
```

Sqlfiddle of same: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f9580a/2)

I have two tables, one (`timestamps`) containing timestamps, and one (`category_timeline`) containing a timeline of categories, that is, we assume the records in `category_timeline` form a continuous non-overlapping timeline assigning a category to each time period.

I want to assign the categories to the `timestamps` table, resulting in:

```
| id |                stamp | category |
|----|----------------------|----------|
|  1 | 2017-10-01T10:05:01Z |     Cat1 |
|  2 | 2017-10-01T11:05:01Z |     Cat1 |
|  3 | 2017-10-01T12:05:01Z |     Cat3 |
|  4 | 2017-10-01T13:05:01Z |     Cat2 |
```

which is the result of the following query:

```
SELECT id, stamp, category FROM timestamps ts 
LEFT JOIN category_timeline tl 
ON   ts.stamp >= tl.begin 
AND  ts.stamp < tl.end
```

However, as soon as the tables get bigger, this operation seems to get exponentially slower, is there a better way to do this, using the assumption that any timestamp only falls within a unique period in the other table.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

```
SELECT ts.id, ts.stamp, 
       (SELECT tl.category
        FROM category_timeline tl 
        WHERE tl.end > ts.stamp
        ORDER BY tl.end ASC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as category
FROM timestamps ts ;
```

Be sure you have an index on `category_timeline(end, category)`.